# Hibernate java jpa query

Tags: sql, hibernate

I've got a problem with select query in my java jpa hibernate. I'm trying to get list of student that are not in the specified group, but the assigment to groups are on the other table.

Here is what i tried but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT e FROM Student e WHERE e != (SELECT c.student FROM listaOsob WHERE c.grupa = :grupa)
```

Comment: Could we see the domain objects and their relationships, e.g. The Student class definition with the associated Group assignment.

Comment: You don't declare the alias `c`. You need to use `not in` to check that a particular item is not in a set of items.

Comment: Thanks Boris. c declaration and the use of "not in" solved the problem. You can add an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't declare the alias `c`. You need to use `NOT IN` to check that a particular item is `NOT IN` a set of items.

Something like

```
SELECT e 
    FROM Student e
    WHERE e NOT IN (
         SELECT c.student
             FROM listaOsob c 
             WHERE c.grupa = :grupa)
```

Ought to do the trick.